Which is more likely recoverable NTFS or Ext4
I've got some 1TB USB external harddrives that are used on Ubuntu systems.  Previously they've been formatted NTFS.
Every now and then something about one of them requires file system repair.  It is rarely the same drive so defective drive is probably not the problem.  If I was looking for why the corruption, my guess would be interrupted transmission as in a cable jiggled, probably during a write operation. This question is about which is more likely to result in a successful repair.
While I do have some Windows systems, these external drives are used exclusively on Ubuntu systems.
There have been instances in the past were I had to use Windows chkdsk for repair
but once in a while I've successfully used the gnome-disk file system repair function.
Today using gnome-disk to perform a minor repair it did enable R/W access to the drive and all the data on it BUT, now windows systems can't mount it and thus, a Microsoft chkdsk cannot be run.
Going forward, would I be more likely to successful repair these 1 TB USB file systems if they are Ext4 format vs NTFS format?
Currently my primary system is XUbuntu 24.04.  I also have a 22.04 and 16.04 version of Xubuntu readily available.
In summary: Given once in a great while a mount might momentarily disconnect - which is more likely to be recoverable NTFS or Ext4

The fact that you constantly need to repair that drive calls for a sanity check on the hardware, you can use GNOME Disks to list the drive's SMART attributes and check for bad sectors. Corruption can happen with any filesystem, corruption that happens this frequently is usually because of a bad drive.

I have several external USB drives no one drive is needing multiple checks.

@kos - I didn't say constantly need to repair a specific drive. Your comment is common - several similar comments on askubuntu.  This is a different situation.  USB connected external drives are connected via a cable.  If that cable gets jiggled, data corruption might happen.  I guess my question could use some refinement

My interpretation of "every now and then" is "constantly", even though that might not be every day or every week. Filesystem shouldn't get corrupted, not even seldomly. What I'm gettting at is: borked USB port, borked cable, borked HDD, user inadvertedly yanking the drive: something may be wrong on a physical level, and usually that's the drive. If it's not, great! But it doesn't mean it's normal for a filesystem to get corrupted. The problem appears to be somewhere else, and if I'm right changing the filesystem won't fix it.


While I do have some Windows systems, these external drives are used exclusively on Ubuntu systems.

In this case the answer is pretty given: a Linux native filesystem with robust support. XFS, EXT4, BTRFS or similar should do nice. The tools available for those filesystems on Linux are much better than the tools available on Linux for NTFS.
In addition the file systems mentioned support Unix specific features, and thus is better suited for Unix like operating systems.
